# JQuery -- Cannot select objects dynamically appended to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

So I have this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(url_dbpath, function(db) {
  var tr;
  //some code

  for (...) {
    tr = $("<tr class='division' id='" + division.name + "'>");
    tr.append("<td>" + division.name + "</td>");
    tr.append(....);
    tr.append("</tr>")
    $('#datatable').append(tr);
  }
```

...which works as expected, correctly appending data that is loaded to the `#datatable` object. The `<tr>` objects have the correct class and ids.

Later I have this:

```
  $("#datatable").on("click", ".division", function() {
    console.log("div");
  });
```

Which also works as expected, adding a listener to the ".division" `<tr>`s.

However, I cannot select the appended rows or data objects in any way. For example, I want to do this:

```
$(".division").hide();
```

but the selector returns an empty array when I call it in the code. I can only select the `#datatable` object and the row of `<th>`s that are there by default. I have tried `$("#datatable").find(".division")` (returns `[]`), `$("#datatable").children().children()` (first one returns `tbody`, second one returns `[]`), selecting by ids, and moving the selectors to the end of the code.

**However**, when I load the page and use the same commands in the console, they return the correct output (in the console).

How do I select the objects?

Comment: Can you set up a [mcve] using either a snippet or jsfiddle? Obviously doing ajax is hard there, but simulate it if possible.

Comment: Also, you mention `tbody` in your question, but it looks like you're appending directly to the `table` element.... perhaps your selector expects the rows to be in the `tbody`?

Comment: I tried `$("#datatable > tbody > tr > .division")` and all the variants of that, but it shouldn't matter anyway. I'll look into setting up a jsfiddle if I can't get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create your elements in another way? I mean, try to build your tr element as

```
$("<tr class='division' id='" + division.name + "'></tr>")
.append("<td>...</td>")
.append("<td>...</td>")
...
.appendTo($('#datatable'))
```